# How can I wait for a window to close before executing a function or opening another window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am using pyqt and in a funtion, I have

```
self.window1 = DialogWindow()
self.window1.show()
#wait for window to close before executing anything else?
self.someOtherFuntion()
```

Comment: if it is a `QDialog`, you can use `self.window1.exec_()`

Comment: It is, should I use .exec_() instead of show()?

Comment: yes you can try it, with `exec_()` you can also check the [return code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec)

Comment: when using .exec_(), it will not show the next window, maybe because next window uses progress bar. I've managed  to call show, then exec_ it fixes my issue that way. Thanks.

Comment: Yes because the `exec_()` call blocks until the dialog is closed. I though this is what you wanted looking at your code. Please provide more code and information. edit: Ok glad it helped.

Comment: how about qwidget